# How can I stop the symbolic x coords to be plotted twice?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, axis, nodes-near-coords

I have created a bar diagram similar to: [How to create symbolic x coords without losing last bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133680/how-to-create-symbolic-x-coords-without-losing-last-bar)

But at a certain width the `symbolic x coords` are plotted twice.
How can I manage the x axis correctly?

Here is my mini example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}



\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        width=1\linewidth,
        height=0.5\linewidth,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        symbolic x coords={CP-Schelle,Mistel-Schelle V2,Mistel-Schelle V4,Mistel-Schelle V4.2D,Gewickelt nach Inspire},
        enlargelimits=true,
        ymin=0,
        nodes near coords,
        x tick label style={
        font=\small,
        text width=1cm,
        align=center
        },
        ybar]
        \addplot[color=gray, fill] coordinates {(CP-Schelle,1.000)};
        \addplot[color=blue, fill] coordinates {(Mistel-Schelle V2,2.459)(Mistel-Schelle V4,3.318)(Mistel-Schelle V4.2D,2.243)(Gewickelt nach Inspire,1.782)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[%
        width=0.6\linewidth,
        height=0.5\linewidth,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        symbolic x coords={CP-Schelle,Mistel-Schelle V2,Mistel-Schelle V4,Mistel-Schelle V4.2D,Gewickelt nach Inspire},
        enlargelimits=true,
        ymin=0,
        nodes near coords,
        x tick label style={
            font=\small,
            text width=1cm,
            align=center
        },
        ybar]
        \addplot[color=gray, fill] coordinates {(CP-Schelle,1.000)};
        \addplot[color=blue, fill] coordinates {(Mistel-Schelle V2,2.459)(Mistel-Schelle V4,3.318)(Mistel-Schelle V4.2D,2.243)(Gewickelt nach Inspire,1.782)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you have PGFPlots v1.13 or newer add `xtick distance=1` to the axis options.

Comment: @StefanPinnow an answer? :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer which was asked for.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=1\linewidth,
        height=0.5\linewidth,
        axis x line=center,
        axis y line=left,
        symbolic x coords={
            CP-Schelle,
            Mistel-Schelle V2,
            Mistel-Schelle V4,
            Mistel-Schelle V4.2D,
            Gewickelt nach Inspire
        },
        enlargelimits=true,
        ymin=0,
        nodes near coords,
        x tick label style={
            font=\small,
            text width=1cm,
            align=center,
        },
        ybar,
        xtick distance=1,               % <-- added
        % use comma as decimal separator
        % (because the x tick labels are (also) in German)
        /pgf/number format/use comma,   % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot [fill,gray] coordinates {
            (CP-Schelle,1.000)
        };
        \addplot [fill,blue] coordinates {
            (Mistel-Schelle V2,2.459)
            (Mistel-Schelle V4,3.318)
            (Mistel-Schelle V4.2D,2.243)
            (Gewickelt nach Inspire,1.782)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: If this answer suits your needs you could -- besides [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it -- think of [accepting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓ next to the answer). By that it disappears from the "still an open question" list. If you need further assistance please edit your question accordingly or ask a Follow-up question. Thanks.